# How to access nutrition facts data from Google search?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to extract the data you get from googling nutrition facts. For example, when you search "1 lb of chicken nutrition facts" it will return links (per usual), but also give valuable nutrition information. I wanted parse the information shown in the nutrition fact section with BeautifulSoup in Python, but have had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory serves, the Google results for generic foods often come from the USDA data. The USDA has an [API](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/doc/) you can probably tap into.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll look into it!

Comment: Saved me a ton of time, thanks!

Comment: In my attempt to parse Google's responses with nutrition data I found that it is true. There are strings pointing to it, like: "fooddata central nutrition name as a number:number", "edamam". It means they may use at least USDA's and Edamam's nutrition data.